# Can't generate a model with Z3

Tags: z3

I have the following example code for the knapsack problem in a file called "knapsack.smt2", which I believe is in smt2 format and I have the latest version of Z3:

```
(declare-const s1 Int)
(declare-const o1 Int)
(declare-const b1 Bool)

(declare-const s2 Int)
(declare-const o2 Int)
(declare-const b2 Bool)

(declare-const s3 Int)
(declare-const o3 Int)
(declare-const b3 Bool)


(declare-const sack-size Int)
(declare-const filled Int)

(assert (< o1 sack-size))
(assert (< o2 sack-size))
(assert (< o3 sack-size))

(assert (>= o1 0))
(assert (>= o2 0))
(assert (>= o3 0))

(assert (=> (not b1)(= o1 o2)))
(assert (=> (not b2)(= o2 o3)))

(assert (=> b1 (= (+ o1 s1) o2)))
(assert (=> b2 (= (+ o2 s2) o3)))
(assert (=> b3 (= (+ o3 s3) filled)))

(assert (=> (not b3) (= o3 filled)))
(assert (<= filled sack-size))

(assert ( = o1 0))


(assert ( = s1 3))
(assert ( = s2 4))
(assert ( = s3 5))
(assert ( = sack-size 20))

(assert ( = filled 13))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

However, when I run "z3 -m knapsack.smt2" I get the following error message:

```
>> z3 -m knapsack.smt2
unsat
(error "line 46 column 10: model is not available")
```

where line 46 is the last line "(get-model)".

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z3 produces models for satisfiable instances. 
Your formula is not satisfiable. Using the constraints

```
(assert ( = o1 0))
(assert ( = s1 3))
(assert ( = s2 4))
(assert ( = s3 5))
(assert ( = filled 13))
```

we have that `o1 = 0` and `s1 = 3`, `s2 = 3`, `s3 = 5`, and `filled = 13`,
Using the constraints

```
(assert (=> (not b1)(= o1 o2)))
(assert (=> b1 (= (+ o1 s1) o2)))
```

We have that `o2 = 0` or `o2 = 3`.

Using

```
(assert (=> (not b2)(= o2 o3)))
(assert (=> b2 (= (+ o2 s2) o3)))
```

We have that `o3 = o2` or `o3 = o2 + 3`
Using

```
(assert (=> b3 (= (+ o3 s3) filled)))
(assert (=> (not b3) (= o3 filled)))
```

We have that `o3 = 8` or `o3 = 13`

Now, we can see the conflict

```
o2 = 0 or o2 = 3
o3 = 8 or o3 = 13
o3 = o2 or o3 = o2 + 3
```

If we try `o2 = 0` we get the unsatisfiable formulas

```
o3 = 8 or o3 = 13
o3 = 0 or o3 = 3
```

If we try `o2 = 3` we get the unsatisfiable formulas

```
o3 = 8 or o3 = 13
o3 = 3 or o3 = 6
```